# How to check user_input validation?

Tags: c++

I am very new to c++ and trying to code Mastermind Game.

I am working on a part where checking a user_input validation.

I would like to assign the value if the user number is less than 8 greater than 1
so any value between 0 and 8.

```
void Game::getUserGuess()
{
    int guess_1, guess_2, guess_3, guess_4;
    std::cout << "Type 4 colors that you want to check: ";
    std::cin >> guess_1 >> guess_2 >> guess_3 >> guess_4;

    gameboard[numGuesses*4] = guess_1;
    gameboard[numGuesses*4 + 1] = guess_2;
    gameboard[numGuesses*4 + 2] = guess_3;
    gameboard[numGuesses*4 + 3] = guess_4;

    currGuess.setGuess(guess_1, guess_2, guess_3, guess_4);
}
```

Here's my code for assigning userGuess. I am trying to assigning value to the gameboard, but I do not want to assign the value if it is not in range. I am fine with the

`currGuess.setGuess(guess_1, guess_2, guess_3, guess_4);`

I am fine with this part, but I want to assign the valid value here:

```
gameboard[numGuesses*4] = guess_1;
gameboard[numGuesses*4 + 1] = guess_2;
gameboard[numGuesses*4 + 2] = guess_3;
gameboard[numGuesses*4 + 3] = guess_4;
```

Comment: What do you wanna do if the guess is not in range? Why just `if` statement is not enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd normally check for valid input before doing anything else, for example:

```
std::array<int, 4> guesses;
while (true)
{
   bool ok = true;
   std::cout << "Type 4 colors that you want to check: ";
   for (auto& guess : guesses)
   {
     std::cin >> guess;
     if (!std::cin // check a valid number was entered
         || guess < 0 || guess > 8)
     {
        ok = false;
        break;
     }
   }
   if (ok)
   {
     break;
   }
   std::cin.clear(); // clear error flags
   std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // discard the rest of the line
   std::cout << "Please enter integers between 0 and 8\n";
}
for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    gameboard[numGuesses*4 + i] = guesses[i];
}
currGuess.setGuess(guesses[0], guesses[1], guesses[2], guesses[3]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the logic! it helped me a lot to understand the steps!

Answer (score 0):

```
int iVal =0;
for (int i=0; i< 4; i++)
{
    std::cin >> iVal;
    if (( iVal > 0) && ( iVal < 8) )
        gameboard[ (numGuesses*4) + i ] = iVal;
    else 
        i--;
}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain what the code does and how it helps.

Comment: @BDL Effectively. I will think about that next time.

Comment: @Landstalker, just to make sure: I wanted to point out that there is the option to edit your answer to add explanations retrospectively.

Comment: @NOhs  Yes i know, thanks. It's just that sometimes I want to help and contribute with the little free time I have, so I try to answer as directly as possible, without taking time to explain things well. but I will think about that next time ^^

Comment: Thank you so much everyone! I will try this code! I feel like I am out of stress now yey!